# How to make Junos PyEZ work via console port?

Tags: python, pyez

I am trying to make Junos PyEZ work via console port (telnet to a Cisco AS2511-RJ terminal server, which is connected to Juniper SRX-240 console port).

The test script is

```
dev = Device(host='X.X.X.X', user='XXX', password='XXXXXXXX',
    mode='telnet', port='2014', gather_facts=True)
try:
    dev.open()
    print(dev.facts)
    print(dev.cli("show version", format='text', warning=False))
except RuntimeError as rte:
    print("Exception: " + str(rte) )
finally:
    dev.close()
```

My problem is that script works only from time to time, but most of the runs are unsuccessful. After unsuccessful attempts, in the log I see something like

```
Nov  8 21:17:29  srxD-2 login: Login attempt for user <close-session/> from host [unknown]
Nov  8 21:17:29  srxD-2 login[39846]: LOGIN_PAM_AUTHENTICATION_ERROR: Failed password for user <close-session/>
Nov  8 21:17:29  srxD-2 login[39846]: LOGIN_FAILED: Login failed for user <close-session/> from host ttyu0
...........
    Nov  8 21:22:41  srxD-2 login: Login attempt for user d-trailer from host [unknown]
...........
```

So PyEZ seems to not always very well deal with my console's screen scraping. Any ideas why this might be and how to fix it? I am using the current master branch of PyEZ from github for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed by adding `console_has_banner=True` option, as shown here:

```
with Device(host='X.X.X.X', user='XXX', password='XXXXXX', mode='telnet', 
        port='2014', gather_facts=True, console_has_banner=True) as dev:
    print(dev.facts)
    print(dev.cli("show version", format='text', warning=False))
```

With this option applied, script now works fine every time.

See more details [in this pull request](https://github.com/Juniper/py-junos-eznc/pull/622).

Answer (score 1):

Can you change your script to use python context manager as shown below (which will take care of closing the connection)? With console connection (screen scraping) if the connection is not closed properly, next time script can get into an issue.

```
with Device(host='X.X.X.X', user='XXX', password='XXXXXXXX',
    mode='telnet', port='2014', gather_facts=True) as dev:
    print(dev.facts)
    print(dev.cli("show version", format='text', warning=False))
```

Can you share details from where the log is coming from as these are not from PyEZ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried changing to context manager and it did not help. Also I was using finally: block which always closed the session in the original version of test script.

Comment: The logs come from Juniper SRX device, messages file. I tried using PyEZ logger with not too much success.

Comment: finally wont help in case of error with connection opening. Say dev.open() itself throws an exception, close call in finally doesn't makes sense.